# Получить исходное название типа в виде строки

Tags: c#, generics, рефлексия

Есть такие свойства:

```
MyClass       Field1 { get; set; }
List<MyClass> Field2 { get; set; }
int?          Field3 { get; set; }
```

У меня есть PropertyInfo. Каким образом можно извлечь/построить строки исходных типов этих свойств? Под исходными, я подразумеваю именно `"MyClass"`, `"List<MyClass>"` и `"int?"`, если использовать nameof и PropertyType.Name я получаю короткую запись у генериков:

```
MyClass
List`1
Nullable`1
```

Может быть, есть какие то встроенные средства, позволяющие построить исходную строку названия типа? (очень не хочется делать эти преобразования вручную)

Comment: Не всё так просто. Дело в том, что .NET не ограничен одним лишь языком C#. Эти типы называются по-разному в различных языках платформы, поэтому фреймворк не может выдать вам имя так, как оно записывается в вашем языке, он даже не в курсе, модуль на каком языке в данный момент выполняется!

Comment: @VladD, Хотите сказать, что в любом случае, будет проще написать самодельное преобразование?

Comment: Боюсь, что именно так

Comment: @VladD, Большое Спасибо что сэкономили мне время). Если кому то нужен ответ на этот вопрос, нашёл подобный на en стеке: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33529925/4401952 Почему я не нагуглил его до того как задал этот вопрос - не понимаю... (facepalm) Да, решения для сахара на вроде ? там нет, но, можно восстановить из обёртки Nullable, при желании. (можно посмотреть комментарий к ответу от  *Igor S* )

Comment: Ага, а также для новомодных кортежей (ValueTuple) и для всякого другого сахара по мере его появления (Ranges, например)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, .NET не ограничен одним лишь языком C#. В языке C# присутствуют алиасы, которых может и не быть в других языках .NET. Затем, формат записи обобщённых типов в (например) VB совсем другой. Поэтому фреймворк не может выдать вам имя так, как оно записывается на C#, ведь он даже не в курсе, модуль на каком языке в данный момент выполняется!

Поэтому без «ручного» преобразования не обойтись.

---

Немного расширил [решение, упомянутое в комментариях](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33529925/276994): добавил `Nullable`, кортежи (туплы), а также «открытые» обобщённые типы. Оганичения этого метода: не детектируются имена элементов кортежей, а также `dynamic`, т. к. информация об этом закодирована не в типе, а в аттрибуте, навешиваемом на поле.

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> typeToAlias =
        new Dictionary<Type, string>
        {
            { typeof(string), "string" },
            { typeof(object), "object" },
            { typeof(bool), "bool" },
            { typeof(byte), "byte" },
            { typeof(char), "char" },
            { typeof(decimal), "decimal" },
            { typeof(double), "double" },
            { typeof(short), "short" },
            { typeof(int), "int" },
            { typeof(long), "long" },
            { typeof(sbyte), "sbyte" },
            { typeof(float), "float" },
            { typeof(ushort), "ushort" },
            { typeof(uint), "uint" },
            { typeof(ulong), "ulong" },
            { typeof(void), "void" }
        };

    public static string GetFriendlyName(this Type type)
    {
        if (typeToAlias.TryGetValue(type, out var reservedName))
            return reservedName;

        if (type.IsArray)
            return type.GetElementType().GetFriendlyName() + "[]";

        var nullableBase = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        if (nullableBase != null)
            return nullableBase.GetFriendlyName() + "?";

        var tupleTypes = GetTupleTypes(type);
        if (tupleTypes != null)
        {
            var tupleTypeNames = tupleTypes.Select(t => t.GetFriendlyName());
            return "(" + string.Join(", ", tupleTypeNames) + ")";
        }

        var friendlyName = type.Name;
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            int backtick = friendlyName.IndexOf('`');
            if (backtick > 0)
                friendlyName = friendlyName.Remove(backtick);
            var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                friendlyName += "<" + new string(',', genericArgs.Length - 1) + ">";
            else
                friendlyName += "<" +
                    string.Join(", ", genericArgs.Select(t => t.GetFriendlyName())) + ">";
        }

        return friendlyName;
    }

    static readonly HashSet<Type> tupleTypes = new HashSet<Type>()
    {
        typeof(ValueTuple<>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>)
    };

    static IEnumerable<Type> GetTupleTypes(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(ValueTuple))
            return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return null;

        var def = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (tupleTypes.Contains(def))
            return type.GetGenericArguments();
        if (def == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>))
        {
            var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
            var lastArg = args[args.Length - 1];
            var restTypes = GetTupleTypes(lastArg);
            if (restTypes != null)
                return args.Take(args.Length - 1).Concat(restTypes);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @test123: Пожалуйста!